# How would I pass a calculated parameter to a url in Django

Tags: python, django, url

I have some parameters that are calculated in the Django view that need to be passed to the url. How would I be able to do that.

The current url pattern:

```
url(r'^hotels/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(?P<region>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)', hotel.views.hotels, name='hotels')
```

The link from my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'hotels' %}?region_id={{ region.id }}">{{ region.name }}</a>
```

And my view:
I get the region_id from the request.

```
def hotels(request):
    region_id = request.GET.get('region_id')
    region = Region.objects.get(id=region_id)
    region_name = region.name
    country_name= region.country.name

    context = {
        'region_id': region_id,
        'region': region_name,
        'country': country_name,
    }
    return render(request, 'hotel/hotels.html', context)
```

I get the region_id from the template, after that I use a query to get the region, the region name and the corresponding country.
The region_name and the country_name should be used in the url.

Until now this does not seem to work.

I hope someone could help me get this done.

,

Comment: That URL pattern doesn't match what you're passing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hotels` url expect two arguments: `country` and `region` you need to pass them to the `url` function:

```
<a href="{% url 'hotels' region.country.name region.id %}">{{ region.name }}</a>
```

Next in the view, take them from the incoming `kwargs`.

```
def hotels(request, country, region):
    pass
```